# What are the commercial anti reversing techniques?

Tags: static-analysis, anti-debugging

I am interested in knowing about what are the latest commercial packages that are out there that deter reverse code engineering. And how do I work around them if necessary ? To be more specific I am talking about ASProtect how do I work around it ?

Comment: Your question is way too wide, you should maybe try to focus on only one aspect of what you are looking for. For example, Armadillo and ASProtect are both packers. You may want to focus on that. I don't know what technique is used in FlexNet, so I can't tell for this one.

Comment: @perror Where do I get information about packers and reversing packed exes ?

Comment: You can perfectly ask the question you have here, but this is a technical site, so you need to focus on a small aspect of the whole thing to get a precise answer. About packers, a starter document could be this [PDF document](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Yason/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-yason-WP.pdf). And, if it raises some questions, do not hesitate to ask for clarification here ! It is fully in the topic of this website.